# Multiport NICs in servers and clusters

Tags: linux, networking, cluster, nic

I wanted to know are multi-port NICs common in server systems? E.g in clustering are they used always?

Comment: "common" is a relative question - multi-port NICs are available, and used when the application warrants them.  Determining what applications warrant them is left as an exercise for the local admin.

Answer (score 3):

Q: Are they common? A: Yes.

Q: Are they used in clustering? A: Usually, but that depends on the specific implementation.

Comment: Are they common?I mean are they cheap?

Comment: Common and cheap are two different things. Are they common? Yes, they are common. Are they cheap? That depends on your definition of cheap and in relation to what.

Answer (score 1):

2: quite yes

1: no. See, decent Server Motherboards have multiple ports, but I would not necessarily Count that as Multi port nic. This is really to decide. It really depends. Define common, define Server System - small web Hosts? Large VM Clusters (running 10g or better infiniband?)

Comment: The OP defined "common" as "cheap" in a comment to joeqwerty's answer.

Comment: So someone has to explicitely order it? Is it expensive?

Comment: Depends. Define expensive. Decent servers cost a LOT and have 64+gb memory - anything smaller these days will get virtualized.The cost of a 400 USD 10g dual port SPF+ card will not add a lot to that.

Answer (score 1):

Servers are meant to serve data to many clients and/or to other servers. For this reason it makes sense that even when not in a clustering configuration most servers come with multiple gigabit NIC's. When configured in a cluster configuration it's very common that servers use a NIC for the management network, one for the storage network and depending on your configuration possibly another for the public network.